# How to join two queries in one using elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

Hi I want to join two queries in one in elasticsearch, but I don't know how to do it: I think I should do an aggregation but I don't know very clear how to do it. Could you help me? My ES version is 5.1.2.

First filter by status and name:

```
POST test_lite/_search
{
   "aggs": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "STATUS": "Now"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "NAME": "PRUDENTL"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Look for in the filtered records for the word filtered in description:

```
POST /test_lite/_search
{
   "query": {
        "wildcard" : { "DESCRIPTION" : "*english*" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only query needed is:

```
POST test_lite/_search
{
   "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "STATUS": "Now"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "NAME": "PRUDENTL"
                     }
                  },
                     {"wildcard" : { "DESCRIPTION" : "*english*" }}
               ]
      } 
   }   
}
```